# What to look for when assembling user generated SQL Sever query in Python from excel?

Tags: python, sql, parsing, code-injection, pyodbc

I am using Excel as a form for users to create, delete and update entries in a SQL Server Table. I am then taking this input into Python via a Data Frame, and creating a SQL string. I then execute it via pyodbc cursor. For instance, below is how I can get a valid and functional Update query.

```
    ParamstoPass=len(ClassCheckMark.columns)
    L_Cols=list()
    L_Vals=list()
    tableName=ClassCheckMark[ClassCheckMark.columns[1]][0]
    SQL_Query='update ' + tableName + ' set '
    for i in range(2, ParamstoPass):
        L_Cols.append(ClassCheckMark[ClassCheckMark.columns[i]].name)
        L_Vals.append(ClassCheckMark[ClassCheckMark.columns[i]][0])

    for i in range(1, len(L_Cols)):
        SQL_Query=SQL_Query+'[' + L_Cols[i] +']=' +"'" + str(L_Vals[i]) +"', "

    SQL_Query=SQL_Query[:-2]+' where ID=' + "'" + str(L_Vals[0]) +"'"
    cursor.execute(SQL_Query)
    cnn.commit()
    cnn.close()
```

But I know there are some undesirable characters that a user can may enter in Excel that will then make it into the query.

So what is the best way to validate the SQL String in python? Should I look for specific characters like '\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"? Or what is the best  industry method for this objective?

And I realize that in general this is not the best way to accomplish the goal of user interaction with a DB, but due to various constrains am going with this approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't create a SQL string from user entered input. Use parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks, so even with Parameters do I need to care about certain characters? I also need to reuse the above Query with tables of various sizes. Can that be accomplished with a single Sproc? or I would need to create a separate stored Procedure for each table?

And I am not too worried about SQL injection, as this will be used to internal group of people. More to avoid user errors. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After building your `L_Cols` and `L_Vals` lists I would suggest validating the column names against the table metadata, constructing a parameterized SQL command, and then executing it. For example:

```python
# test data
L_Cols = ['ID', 'FirstName', 'Photo']
L_Vals = [123, 'bob', None]
tablename = "People"

# validate list of column names
valid_column_names = [x.column_name for x in cursor.columns(tablename).fetchall()]
for col_name in L_Cols:
    if col_name not in valid_column_names:
        raise ValueError("[{0}] is not a valid column name for table [{1}]".format(col_name, tablename))
# build SQL command text
SQL_Query = "UPDATE [" + tablename + "] SET "
SQL_Query += ", ".join("[" + x + "]=?" for x in L_Cols[1:])
SQL_Query += " WHERE [" + L_Cols[0] + "]=?"
print(SQL_Query)  # UPDATE [People] SET [FirstName]=?, [Photo]=? WHERE [ID]=?
# move ID value to the end of the list of parameters
params = L_Vals[1:] + L_Vals[0:1]
print(params)  # ['bob', None, 123]

# (edit by OP)
# as in my case, some elements were of unicode markup, which threw
#   ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 
#   param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105'). 
# May need to add params=[str(x) for x in params]

cursor.execute(SQL_Query, params)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gord Thompson, 
In fact, I am already doing column validation like this:
Columns=list(ClassCheckMark.columns[2:].values)
TemptDataSenderTab=pd.DataFrame(columns=Columns)
TemptDataSenderTab.to_sql(tableName, engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)

And regarding cursor.execute(SQL_Query, params). How does it work? Or how is it different from passing a fully assembled string? Does it validate the skeleton query structure in DB before inserting values? Sort of like a SP would do?

Comment: *"how is [a parameterized query] different from passing a fully assembled string?"* - It protects you from SQL injection vulnerabilities, essentially automatically doing what you asked about in your question: escaping quotes in string values, handling "funny" characters, etc.. *"Does it validate the skeleton query structure in DB before inserting values?"* Not really. It creates the appropriate call to the SQL Server (usually some variant of `exec sp_prepexec ...`) and sends it along. The server will return an error if the call doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks @Gord Thompson. I like your solution in regards to cursor.execute(SQL_Query, params). But I am still confused as to how it works.. Where does the bad character validation happen? Or did you mean that it does not happen explicitly, but rather as a returned error for when that call to the SQL Server is executed? In other words, if a bad character is found, it errors out until a user sends in the right set of values, such that the query structure is as per the empty SQL_Query? Thanks again.

Comment: *"Where does the bad character validation happen?"* - It happens in the `execute` method of the `Cursor` object when it creates the calls that get sent to the SQL Server. Those calls will be syntactically correct and will not have SQL injection vulnerabilities but they may still be invalid if, for example, a string parameter value is too large to fit into the specified column (e.g., trying to insert 'Gord' into a VARCHAR(3) column).